# Fast bitwise comparison of unaligned bit streams

Tags: c++

I have two bit streams `A[1..a]` and `B[1..b]`, where `a` is always smaller than `b`. Now, given an index `c` in `B`, I want to know if `A` matches the area `B[c..c+a-1]` (assume c+a-1<=b always hold).

I can't just use `memcmp` because `A` and `B[c..c+a-1]` are not necessarily byte-aligned.

So I have a custom function that compares `A` and `B[c..c+a-1]` bitwise, where `B` is encoded within a class that performs bit operations. This is my C++ code:

```c
#include<cstddef>
#include<cstdint>

struct bitstream{

    constexpr static uint8_t word_bits = 64;
    constexpr static uint8_t word_shift = 6;
    const static size_t masks[65];

    size_t *B;

    inline bool compare_chunk(const void* A, size_t a, size_t c)  {

        size_t n_words = a / word_bits; 
        size_t left = c & (word_bits - 1UL);
        size_t right = word_bits - left;
        size_t cell_i = c >> word_shift;

        auto tmp_in = reinterpret_cast<const size_t *>(A);
        size_t tmp_data;

        //shift every cell in B[c..c+a-1] to compare it against A
        for(size_t k=0; k < n_words - 1; k++){
            tmp_data = (B[cell_i] >> left) & masks[right];
            tmp_data |= (B[++cell_i] & masks[left]) << right;
            if(tmp_data != tmp_in[k]) return false;
        }

        size_t read_bits = (n_words - 1) << word_shift;
        return (tmp_in[n_words - 1] & masks[(a-read_bits)]) == read(c + read_bits, c+a-1);
    }

    inline size_t read(size_t i, size_t j) const{
         size_t cell_i = i >> word_shift;
         size_t i_pos = (i & (word_bits - 1UL));
         size_t cell_j = j >> word_shift;
         if(cell_i == cell_j){
             return (B[cell_i] >> i_pos) & masks[(j - i + 1UL)];
         }else{
             size_t right = word_bits-i_pos;
             size_t left = 1+(j & (word_bits - 1UL));
             return ((B[cell_j] & masks[left]) << right) | ((B[cell_i] >> i_pos) & masks[right]);
         }
    }
};

const size_t bitstream::masks[65]={0x0,
                                   0x1,0x3, 0x7,0xF,
                                   0x1F,0x3F, 0x7F,0xFF,
                                   0x1FF,0x3FF, 0x7FF,0xFFF,
                                   0x1FFF,0x3FFF, 0x7FFF,0xFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFF,0x3FFFF, 0x7FFFF,0xFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFF,0x3FFFFF, 0x7FFFFF,0xFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFF,0x3FFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFF,0xFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
                                   0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}
```

The function `read` belongs to the class that wraps `B` and reads an area of `B` of most 64 bits.

The code above works, but it seems to be the bottleneck of my application (I run it exhaustively over massive inputs).

Now, my **question** is: do you know if there is a technique to compare `A` and `B[c..c+a-1]` faster?

I know I could use SIMD instructions, but I don't think it will produce a significant improvement as `B` is encoded in 64-bit cells.

Here are some extra details:

1. `A` is usually short (maybe 20 or 30 64-bit cells), but there is not guarantee. It could also be arbitrarily large, although always smaller than `B`.
2. I can't make any assumption about `A`'s encoding. It could be `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`. That is the reason I pass it as `void*` to the function.
3. Link to godbolt with the code above compiling [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Kvavn76qo)

Thanks!

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior for both aliasing and alignment violations. (And not only in theory. This will cause miscompilation when used eventually on at least GCC and Clang with default settings, plus optimization.) You can only use `unsigned char`, no other (unsigned integral) type, to access the data. So no `size_t`. SIMD is a separate matter though.

Comment: Could you post a code that actually compiles? Some things I can figure out (like word_shift), but others I can't (like mask). It's hard to give suggestions if I can't check what the code compiles to (for example on godbolt.org).

Comment: OK, I updated the code with some extra details but kept it simple. It is unclear to me why casting void* to size_t* is a problem. The code above compiles without errors or warning in godbolt, even using compiler optimizartions (see my the link in my updated question).

Comment: @AAA Objects in C++ can only be accessed through types that are _similar_ to the actual type of the object. _Similar_ here basically means equal up to `const` qualifications. There are only few exceptions, e.g. for signed/unsigned variants of the same integer type and when casting _to_ `char`/`unsigned char` or `std::byte`. Not following these restrictions is known as a (strict) aliasing violation and causes undefined behavior. There will not be any warning for this from the compiler. It will simply make the assumption that this doesn't happen when optimizing.

Comment: That's why `reinterpret_cast` is always dangerous and should only be used in very specific, carefully checked circumstances. That aside, when casting to `size_t*` you also need to make sure that the original pointer is aligned at least as strictly as the alignment of `size_t` and that doesn't seem guaranteed from what you are showing. The alignment of `unsigned char` is `1`, so it is always fine in that case.

Comment: And then there is also the potential issue that the buffer that the `void*` points to doesn't have an integer multiple size of `size_t`, in which case you can't access the end of it through that type regardless of alignment and aliasing. I didn't check whether your code handles that correctly. `unsigned char` is guaranteed to have size `1`, so no problem there.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for the clarification,  I wasn't aware of these restrictions (I am not really an expert on C++). I will change to unsigned char* and use memcmp within the loop to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

- as noted before, you can't just cast A to size_t*. You either need to go byte-by-byte, or check the beginning and end that's not 8-byte aligned separately
- move the declaration of tmp_data inside the loop as a single 'size_t const tmp_data' assignment, refer to B[cell_i] and B[cell_i+1], and increment cell_i in the for statement. That way the compiler can do loop unrolling (at least it can detect that it can much more easily).
- finally, if memory is not an issue, then you can keep 8 copies of B (each shifted by a bit to the right), and use the one where B[c] is the beginning of a new byte. Then you can use memcmp (which will presumably give you the fastest code).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I will try the second solution. Keeping 8 copies of B is actually a problem for me because this bitstream is massive, several GBs. :)